# Bad print bed adhesion of white PLA, no problems with transparent uncolored PLA?

Tags: pla, adhesion

I had problems with print bed adhesion when using white PLA (Arctic White) but no problems when using other colors. So I tried to print three bottom layers with transparent PLA and all other layers with white PLA. I did not change any setting and printed both tries one after another using the same .stl file.

There was some warping of the printed ring too. No problems when using transparent plus white PLA.

[image: Photo of two printed rings]

Right: white PLA only, left: transparent PLA bottom layers plus white PLA above. View of the bottom sides.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Comment: check filament diameters with a caliper or micrometer.

Comment: @Abel I checked both filameters with a caliper, both 1.75 mm.

Comment: I've never had poor adhesion make strait lines in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Same G-code slice? The main cause of warping is temperature. If this is kept as a control variable and you have these results, it may be because of a different temperature the filament requires. Check the filament specs and adjust the bed/nozzle temperature to make the temperature difference smaller.

Edit: Another reason it might be needing different temperatures is because of absorbing moisture.

Comment: The same bed/nozzle temperatures for both rings.

Comment: It's not unusual for colored filaments to have different optimum temperature when compared to natural/un-colored filament.

Comment: Point being, maybe it *shouldn't* be the same temperature on both filaments.

Comment: Higher temperature likely will fix this, but the reason isn't the materials needing different temperatures. It's likely moisture-contaminated filament.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was displaced by a factory reset of the 3D printer FlashForge Adventurer 3.

[image: Photo of two versions]

Right: white PLA only, left: transparent PLA bottom layers plus white PLA above. View of the bottom sides. No difference of print bed adhesion now.

The reason of the problem was not found, but print bed adhesion is good after the factory reset for both white and transparent PLA.

Comment: This sounds unlikely to have been the actual cause unless you'd messed with esteps or something.